# how to config remote git repo inside of VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wanna to clone one of my github repo to VSCode so that I can push my code to github, but I don't know how to do it ?

VSCode version :1.18
MacOS 10.12.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning of code is not related to VSCode, you can use any terminal to clone a Git Repo, if Git is installed on your local machine.

You can open the terminal integrated in VSCode by following instructions given [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).

After opening the terminal, you can clone the Repo via folowing command

```
git clone https://XXXX.XXX.com
```

Comment: thanks very much Vipin Kumar, but when I clone the Repo to my local , and modified the file , seems I cannot push the changes to the remote Repo ,and vscode reminds me "Repository is not configured with any remote repositories to push"

Comment: can you check `git remote -a`

Comment: as you can see when I run the command like you say , hit 
error: unknown switch `a'

Comment: by bad.  please use `-v` instead of -a

Comment: you can follow this instruction to manually add remote address https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/